# How to edit a message after 5 seconds but not clear previous message content before

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a array like:
`["text1", "text2", "text3", etc]`

I want to send each of them into a message after 5 seconds and not clear previous value before.

Furthermore, I tried to use forEach to edit and add each value of the array into the message but
sometimes it's not work as I expected and can't run next line of code.

My code:

```
obj.firstText = obj.text.shift();
let msg = await message.reply(`${obj.firstText}`);
let mess = await getLastEditedMessage(msg, obj);

function getLastEditedMessage(msg, obj) {
    return new Promise(result => {
        obj.text.forEach((value, index) => {
            setTimeout(async () => {
                if (index === (obj.text.length - 1)) {
                    msg = await msg.edit(`${msg}\n${value}`);
                    result(msg);
                } else {
                    msg = await msg.edit(`${msg}\n${value}`);
                }
            }, index * 3000)
        })
    })
}
```

I'm expecting a message will be like:

```
text1
(After 5 seconds) text2
(After 5 seconds) text3
(After 5 seconds) etc
```

Comment: Please include a code snippet of your working code so that we can help you modify it

Comment: "sometime it's not work as i expected and can't run next line of code" Could you explain in more detail what happens? For example, do you get an error message from something? If so, what is the error message?

Comment: When i restart bot it's run properly. But after few times use it's just send one value of array and it's not run next line of code then it's stuck in there. Sometime it's send a message with undefined value

Comment: @ĐứcNguyễn, have you checked my answer?

Comment: Yeah i checked but it's still have same problem. Sometime it's ignore `let msg = await message.reply(${obj.firstText})` and start immediately `let mess = await getLastEditedMessage`

Comment: oh i got it. thank Swanand Taware so much

Answer (score 1):

I found a problem. Thank Swanand Taware so much for helping me.

```
obj.firstText = obj.text[0];
let msg = message.reply(`${obj.firstText}`).then((msg) => getLastEditedMessage(msg, obj))

function getLastEditedMessage(msg, arr){
var arrLen = arr.text.length;
var index = 1;
var myInterval = setInterval(()=>{
    msg.edit(`${msg}\n${arr.text[index]}`)
    index++;
   console.log(arrLen,index);
    if(index >= arrLen){
      clearInterval(myInterval);
    } 
    },3000);
```

}